# ¿Cómo modificar el valor de un elemento XML C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Necesitó modificar el valor de un elemento XML (MymeType), trate con este código pero no funciona

El XML actual se ve así:

```
-<xades:DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#Reference-6cc7af2a-a47d-414e-a4da-989f67578741">
<xades:MimeType>text/xml</xades:MimeType>
<xades:Encoding>UTF-8</xades:Encoding>
</xades:DataObjectFormat>
```

Necesitó que se vea de esta manera:

```
-<xades:DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#Reference-6cc7af2a-a47d-414e-a4da-989f67578741">
<xades:MimeType>application/octet-stream</xades:MimeType>
<xades:Encoding>UTF-8</xades:Encoding>
</xades:DataObjectFormat>
```

Mi Codigo:

```
private string SetMymeType(string path, XmlDocument xmlDoc)
        {
            string result = "";
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            xmlDoc.Load(path);
            try
            {
                string URI = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#";
                XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
                nsManager.AddNamespace("xades", URI);
                XmlNode MimeType = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//xades:MimeType", nsManager);
                if (MimeType != null)
                {
                    MimeType.Value = "application/octet-stream";
                }
           xmlDoc.Save(path);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { result = ex.ToString(); }
            return result;

        }
```

Comment: Listo @Mariano , igual no lo hace...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es `MimeType.Value`, sino `MimeType.InnerText` o `MimeType.InnerXml`.

En tu XML `<xades:MimeType>text/xml</xades:MimeType>`, `text/xml` es en realidad un nodo diferente (un nodo de texto, tipo `XmlText`). El `.Value` de ese `XmlText` es `"text/xml"`.

Sin embargo, el nodo que seleccionaste es el `<xades:MimeType>` (que es el padre de ese nodo de texto). Para Elementos, `.Value` devuelve siempre `null` ([ver tabla](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value(v=vs.110).aspx)).

[**XmlNode.InnerText**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innertext(v=vs.110).aspx) es la forma de asignar texto (la propiedad se asegura de escapar cualquier caracter incorrecto, por ejemplo escapa un `"<"` para que no lo interprete como que abre una etiqueta).

```
MimeType.InnerText = "application/octet-stream";
```